# Eliminar letras o caracteres de una palabra con regex

Tags: javascript, regex

estoy aprendiendo acerca de la regex, y mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo eliminar letras(en esta caso las vocales(aeiou)) de una palbra dada?.

Hice lo siguiente mediante JS, pero me sale a la inversa o sea en vez de eliminar las vocales me las muestra y me elimina las consonantes(y eso en algunos casos)

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

```js
const regex = /\w(?!a|e|i|o|u)/g
const txt = "aeious"


console.log(txt.match(regex));
```

Comment: Usa `/[^aeiou]/g`. Básicamente matchea todo lo que no sea una vocal. Otra opción sería `txt.replaceAll(/[aeiou]/g, "")` para remplazar todas las vocales por cadenas vacías.

Comment: En general, si  quieres eliminar letras, usa replace o replaceAll. `match` es más para extraer patrones de un cadena.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funcionó :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
const regex = /[aeiou]/g
const txt = "Hola"

console.log(txt.replaceAll(regex, "")); // Hl
```